# unused assigned variables in Unity character skeleton mapping

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a motion-capture system that I use to animate a character (non-mecanim) so obviously I have to map the motion data onto the character's bones and segments.

Here is how I do it, but since the joints names are only used within the `mapBones()` method, I get quite a few amber warnings at the Unity console that `warning CS0219: The variable JtHips is assigned but its value is never used.`

I get one for each bone! It does not look professional, so I am wondering if there is any way I could get rid of them? All the posts I have checked out, of course recommend using them, but in this case, they are being used internally by the mapping function...

```
private Dictionary<MoCapSegment, ChrBones> jointsDict;

public enum MoCapSegment
        {
            Pelvis = 0,
            // many more ...           
            Neck = 48,
            Head = 49
        }

public enum ChrBones
        {
            JtHips = 0,
            // many more ...            
            JtNeckA = 48,
            JtSkullA = 49
        }

protected void mapBones()
        {
            jointsDict = new Dictionary<MoCapSegment, ChrBones>();

            GameObject JtHips = transform.Find("CharacterRoot/JtJtHips").gameObject;
            jointsDict.Add(MoCapSegment.Pelvis, ChrBones.JtHips);

            // all the rest
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN do the following, but be careful

```
#pragma warning disable 0414
```

Specifically,

```
#pragma warning disable 0168// variable declared but not used.
#pragma warning disable 0219// variable assigned but not used.
#pragma warning disable 0414// private field assigned but not used.
```

I agree with you that this problem is infuriating.

Another thing you can do is this...

```
public void check<T>(T x){}
```

and then you can

```
private Whatever JtHips = whatever; // throws warning since never used

check(JtHips);  // avoid warning like this
```

As always it's a great chance to use an extension

```
public static class YourExtensions
  {
  public static void Nothing<T>(this T x) {}
```

and then you can

```
JtHips.Nothing();
JtNeck.Nothing();
JtSkull.Nothing();
etc...
```

All that being said, it's a ***very bad idea to suppress warnings***, of course. Take care.

Comment: Thank you. The second one is genius!